# RabbitMQ 1 Million Connection Configuration

Tags: rabbitmq

I am new with RabbitMQ and in my requirement I need to connect as many as 1 million connection to RabbitMQ. 
I already tried with a single node with 2CPU and 2GB RAM and it can only handle about 10k connection, what can I do to improve this number?
FYI, I already tried the networking configuration in RabbitMQ Documentation for now. 
I am working with the RabbitMQ Cluster for now but how many nodes do I need to achieve the 1 million concurrent connection if single node can only handle about 10k connection.

Comment: In most cases, I don't think you really need to have 1 million connections on a queue. Could you please give more about the background?

Comment: @TeddyMa..Hi thanks for the response. I need 1 million connections to multiple queue not just 1 queue. Let's say that I have about 100k queues and 1 million connections to those queues.

Comment: Do all these queues have to work together and are related to each other? If not, we could divide and conquer. Any big system consists of many small sub-systems. And the architecture of each sub-system might be much simpler. In terms of connections, each sub-system might not really need 1 million that much. Also, RabbitMQ is super flexible to be part of different architectures as different roles. So only with enough details of scenario background, we could design reasonable solutions.

Comment: @TeddyMa.. Hi, the queues not related to each other, 1 connection connect exactly to a unique queue. Do you think using a rabbitmq cluster will help in this case?

Comment: To have 1 million queues doesn't sound correct. Could you explain more about the real problem you are trying to solve? I mean, to use or not use RabbitMQ as part of the architecture is only a tech decision, but what's the real biz problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You don't need a ton more queues. You will definitely need a cluster that load balances correctly and, as stated, you will want to divide those clusters. CloudAMQP makes bare-bones profit and 80,000 simultaneous connections is the absolute max on a large cluster costing about $5400 per month. Is there a way to avoid 1 million connections altogether? I wrote a Rust program that has a handful of consumers pushing messages to channels on servers with > 100 threads.